# Trig Substitution Help

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals, completing-the-square

I need to integrate the following using trigonometric substitution. I also know that I need to do the following by completing the square in the denominator, but I can't seem to figure it out.

$$\int \frac {x^2+1}{(x^2-2x+2)^2} dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete the square by adding and subtracting $1$ inside the parens to get $$\frac{x^2+1}{(x-1)^2+1}.$$
Then make the substitution $u=x-1$ to get

$$ \int \frac{(u+1)^2+1}{(u^2+1)^2 } \; du.$$  Now trig sub $u=\tan t$.

Comment: The irreducible factor in the denominator is squared.

Comment: Can you explain how/why we have to long division, have not learned it in my class and have to show/explain my steps

Comment: Rats.  Hand me my spec's.  Stand by for an edit.

Comment: @ZackSloan  It was my mistake.  But in general, the first step in integrating an improper rational expression is to do long division and express it as a polynomial plus a proper rational expression.

Comment: Think I got it, thanks.